# How to use lambda and predicate for example if you disagree with the java.net.URI implementation?

Tags: java, lambda, predicate

My goal is to override the `isAbsolute` method from the `java.net.URI` to follow the RFC3986 about absolute-uri which invalidate a uri if it have `fragment`. Unfortunately, I can not extends the class.

Someone at SO recommended me to use Predicate and String. Unfortunately, he deleted his answer. So, I am sort of being creative right now.

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class PredicateAsParameter {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = new URI("http://www.example.com/#fragment");

    boolean isAbsolute1val = isAbsolute1met(uri);
    System.out.println(isAbsolute1val);

    boolean isAbsolute2val = isAbsolute2met(uri, (x) -> x.getScheme() != null && x.getAuthority() != null && x.getFragment() == null);
    System.out.println(isAbsolute2val);
  }
  public static Boolean isAbsolute1met(URI uri) {
    return uri.getScheme() != null && uri.getAuthority() != null && uri.getFragment() == null;
  }

  public static Boolean isAbsolute2met(URI uri, Predicate<URI> condition) {
    return condition.test(uri);
  }
}
```

My expected result is that I can use the `Predicate`, somehow find new way to write code.

My actual result is that I have not figured out why to use Predicate. I feel a bit off and somehow feel that I am testing against the Object instead of against the attributes of the Object by using the Predicate and Lambda. So, I feel, that I am using it wrong.

Comment: FYI, the deleted answer said "If you disagree with the API, you could make your own definition and write `Predicate<String> isURIMyAbsolute = uri -> uri.isAbsolute() && uri.getFragment() == null;`"

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I have two questions. How do you get the deleted answer? And, are you sure `Predicate<String>` is the correct one instead of `Predicate<URI>`?

Comment: Seeing deleted answers is a [privilege you get at 10.000 rep points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). About `Predicate<String>` vs `Predicate<URI>`, looks like you're right. I just copy-pasted what was in the answer. Probably one of the reasons the original answerer decided to delete it.